# What does the "cov" mean in a velvet assembler generated contig name?

Tags: dna-sequencing, sequence-analysis, sequence-assembly

A exmaple of a contig name generated by velvet assembler:

```
NODE_127_length_39203_cov_244.873016
```

What does `cov_244.873016` mean?

It sounds like `coverage`. Does it mean `reads coverage` or other statistical description of the contig?

Comment: It means coverage

Comment: covariate perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

It means **k-mer coverage**. From the [velvet manual](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/~zerbino/velvet/Manual.pdf):

> **4.2.1 The contigs.fa file**
>
> This fasta file contains the sequences of the contigs longer than 2 k
>   , where k is the word-length used in velveth.  If you have specified a
>   *min_contig_length* threshold, then the contigs shorter than that value are omitted. Note  that  the  length  and  coverage  information
>   provided  in  the  header  of each contig should therefore be
>   understood in k-mers and in k-mer coverage (cf. 5.2 ) respectively. 
>   E.g.  for a 500bp contig and a k-mer length of 21, the length in the
>   header will be 480.

Comment: +1 for resisting the urge to say RTFM--I guess that is one of the many reasons we elected you as a moderator: impulse control.

Comment: @mdperry Haha.. I'm working on it actually :)